# AdamOptimizer returns invalid datatype error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been struggling to fix this for the past couple of days, any help would be appreciated.

I have a network that outputs numeric locations `x,y coordinates` in an image, hence the `int32` datatype. The output is of size `(2,2)`. Ground truth also has the locations as `int32`.

Then I run, following two lines of code:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred_cls))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(cost)
```

and receive following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid type tf.int32 for Mean_7:0, expected: [tf.float32, tf.float64, tf.float16, tf.bfloat16].
```

I understand that average should be a float value, but if I convert predicted value to float, I start getting 'No gradients provided' error.

I have also tried to use `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` of Tensorflow to turn my problem into a classification problem, but same error. I'd really appreciate any help with the solution.

**Code**

Code for Input and Labels

```
x_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size_flat*num_channels], name='x_pred')
x_pred_image = tf.reshape(x_p, [-1, 10, 10, num_channels])
k = tf.constant(npatches)
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2, 2], name='y_true')
y_true_cls = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2, 2], name='y_true_cls')
```

Convolution Layer

```
def new_weights(shape, layer_name):
    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
    return tf.Variable(initializer(shape), name=layer_name+'_W')

def new_bias(length, layer_name):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[length]), name=layer_name+'_b')

def new_conv_layer(input,
                   num_input_channels,
                   filter_size,
                   num_filters,
                   name_scope,
                   layer_name='',
                   use_pooling=True):

    with tf.name_scope(name_scope):
        shape = [filter_size, filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters]
        weights = new_weights(shape, layer_name)
        biases = new_bias(num_filters, layer_name)

        layer = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(input=input, filter=weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME'), biases, name=layer_name)

        if use_pooling:
            layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=layer,
                                   ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                                   strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                   padding='SAME', name=layer_name+'_max')

        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer, name=layer_name+'_activation')

    return layer, weights
```

Fully Connected Layer

```
def new_fc_layer(input,
                num_inputs,
                num_outputs,
                name_scope,
                layer_name='',
                use_relu=True):

    with tf.name_scope(name_scope):
        weights = new_weights([num_inputs, num_outputs], layer_name)
        biases = new_bias(num_outputs, layer_name)

        layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(input, weights),biases,name=layer_name)
    #     layer = tf.matmul(input, weights) + biases

        if use_relu:
            layer = tf.nn.relu(layer, layer_name+'_activation')

    return layer
```

Custom Layer Code

```
with tf.name_scope(name_scope):
    resh_inp = tf.reshape(input, [-1, 10, 10])
    input_shape = tf.shape(resh_inp)
    rows, cols = input_shape[1], input_shape[2]
    d_rows, d_cols = 2, 2
    subm_rows, subm_cols = rows - d_rows + 1, cols - d_cols + 1
    ii, jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(subm_rows), tf.range(subm_cols), indexing='ij')
    d_ii, d_jj = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(d_rows), tf.range(d_cols), indexing='ij')

    subm_ii = ii[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis] + d_ii
    subm_jj = jj[:, :, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis] + d_jj
    subm = tf.gather_nd(resh_inp[0, :, :], tf.stack([subm_ii, subm_jj], axis=-1), name=layer_name + "_gather")
    subm_sum = tf.reduce_sum(subm, axis=(2, 3), name=layer_name + "_subm_sum")
    _, top_idx = tf.nn.top_k(tf.reshape(subm_sum, [-1]), tf.minimum(k, tf.size(subm_sum)), name=layer_name + "_top_idx")
    top_row = top_idx // subm_cols
    top_col = top_idx % subm_cols
    result = tf.stack([top_row, top_col], axis=-1, name=layer_name + "_result")
    result_shape = tf.shape(result)
    result = tf.reshape(result, [-1, result_shape[0], result_shape[1]], name=layer_name + "_shaped_result")
```

Result from above code is passed as `y_pred_cls` in below code

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred_cls))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(cost)
```

Comment: The error that is thrown when you cast the variables to float occurs whenever the optimizer fails to calculate the gradient. Post all of your code so that we can check for ops that do not support gradients.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the code in my original post. Please feel free to let me know if there's any confusion. would be happy to answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well obviously there are no parameters (and with parameters I mean ``tf.Variable()``) in your code that could be tweaked by the optimizer. If this is all of your code, how should the AdamOptimizer adjust your model to the data?

Comment: Sorry, should've pasted the other code before. It's there now though. Before the custom layer, there are two layers, one convolutional and another fully connected, then comes the so called 'Custom' layer. I have included the function that create those layers as well.

Comment: What bothers me here is your implementation of ``new_weights``. The line ``initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()`` returns an init object, not a matrix. Afterwards, in the return statement, there are two strange things: Firstly, the initial value of a variable cannot be an init object. Secondly, you cannot give a shape param to the initializer, as you have already created the object with defaults in the line above. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: I understand that, but if I remove the custom layer, which extracts locations from an image, everything works fine. I think the problem is in 'custom layer code'...